# Combining 2 groupby outputs with lambda using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by

Table(df):

```
 customer_id Order_date 
     1       2015-01-16      
     1       2015-01-19      
     2       2014-12-21      
     2       2015-01-10      
     1       2015-01-10
     3       2018-01-18
     3       2017-03-04
     4       2019-11-05
     4       2010-01-01
     3       2019-02-03
     3       2019-01-01
     3       2018-01-01
```

**Output I want:**

Code to extract number of order_dates (where there were at least 3 transactions by a person) using groupby for each customer id and also I need say the most recent transaction dates.

```
        Customer_id     No_order_date    Most recent order date
            1                3          2015-01-19

            3                5          2019-02-03
```

**Code tried so far:**

```
 freq = 3 
 df.groupby('customer_id')['order_date'].nunique().loc[lambda x: 
 x>=freq].reset_index().rename(columns={'order_date':'No_Order_Dates'})

        Customer_id     No_Order_Dates    
            1                3                              
            3                5          


 df.groupby('customer_id')['order_date'].max().reset_index().rename(columns= 
 {'order_date':'Most recent order Date'})

       Customer_id              Most recent order date
            1                          2015-01-19
            3                          2019-02-03
```

**How can I combine the two groupby outputs? I need both in a single table** (is there a way to join without using concatenate or merge or will i have to use concatenate/merge only)

Comment: `df.groupby('customer_id')['Order_date'].agg({'Order_date_nunique':'nunique','Most recent order date':'max'})` ?

Comment: or named agg: `df.groupby('customer_id').agg(Order_date = ('Order_date','nunique'),Most_recent_order_date = ('Order_date','max'))` no problem :)

Comment: This is better since i can also aggregate other columns using named aggregations

Comment: df.groupby('customer_id').agg(No_transactions=('order_date','nunique().loc[lambda x: x>=7]',Most_recent_order_date = ('order_date', 'max')) is not working. Lambda doesnt work in case of aggregations?  @anky_91

Comment: Please reopen the question'

Comment: added answer, please let me know how it goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same named aggregation with `.loc[]` after the groupby:

```
(df.groupby('customer_id').agg(No_transactions=('Order_date','nunique'),
           Most_recent_order_date = ('Order_date', 'max'))
            .loc[lambda x: x['No_transactions']>=3])
```

Or query:

```
(df.groupby('customer_id').agg(No_transactions=('Order_date','nunique'),
       Most_recent_order_date = ('Order_date', 'max'))
        .query("No_transactions>=3"))
```

---

```
             No_transactions Most_recent_order_date
customer_id                                        
1                          3             2015-01-19
3                          5             2019-02-03
```